# Tortoise Delete File System Repository

Tags: tortoisesvn, repository

I am working on a file system repository with Tortoise.

I deleted the initial folder where I created the repository.

The folder which I added to the old repository, when I try to add to a new repository, the error message appears:

Repository UUID '6df16c57-c740-ea49-ab7f-fcd22d7f7cb9' doesn't match expected

Is there a way to simply clear out the settings for the old repository?  So that I could perform the importing of the folder to add into the new repository in a clean slate.

BTW this is my tortoise version (if it is of any help):

TortoiseSVN 1.5.8, Build 15348 - 32 Bit , 2009/02/13 18:06:18

Subversion 1.5.5,

apr 1.2.12

apr-utils 1.2.12

berkeley db 4.4.20

neon 0.28.3

OpenSSL 0.9.8i 15 Sep 2008

zlib 1.2.3

Basically, all I want to do is to clear up the repository which I earlier created so that it is like starting from scratch over again.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this TortoiseHg you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way to do this with TortoioseSVN:

[unversion a working copy](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/343)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you have [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed, you can use the [unsvn](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/UnSVN.shtml) utility to remove all the ".svn" folders.

Comment: What is Cygwin? is it packaged with tortoise itself?

Comment: No, Cygwin isn't packaged with Tortoise. Cygwin is a bundle of UNIX tools and libraries that have been ported to Windows. It provides the bare-bones essentials needed to run UNIX shell scripts and to generate WIN32 binaries from code targeted for UNIX systems.

Comment: The "unsvn" program is a BASH Shell Script, which is why you would need to have Cygwin to run it on Windows. (Cygwin includes a copy of the BASH Shell, ported to Windows).

Comment: Is there no other way to simply delete the folder where the svn repository was initially created and clear the tags for the files that were initially checked in/out?

I have deleted the folder where the original repository was created but the folders and files which I added originally are still marked with the Tortoise Icons.

Comment: Yes, you can recursively go through all the folders and delete any folder named ".svn".